# How to bind tables in a for loop

Tags: r, rbind

I am trying to create a table that summarizes data from a dataset. I have:

```
set.seed(123) 
age <- runif(100, 1, 100)
gender <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace=TRUE)
bmi <- rep(c("Normal"), 100)
height <- runif(100, 150, 190)
smoker <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace=TRUE)

finaldata <- data.frame(age, gender, bmi, height, smoker)
str(finaldata)
continuous <- finaldata[ ,c(1, 4)]
categorical <- finaldata[ ,c(2, 3, 5)]


Table1 <- function(CONT, CAT, DIGITS=2){
table_cont <- matrix(0, ncol=2, nrow=ncol(CONT))
for (i in 1:ncol(CONT)){
table_cont[i, ] <- c(round(mean(CONT[ ,i]), DIGITS), round(sd(CONT[ ,i]), DIGITS))
}

cats <- function(VARIABLE){
table_cat <- matrix(0, ncol=2, nrow=dim(table(CAT[ ,VARIABLE])))
for (i in 1:dim(table(CAT[ ,VARIABLE]))){
table_cat[i, ] <- c(table(CAT[ ,VARIABLE])[i], paste(round(prop.table(table(CAT[ ,VARIABLE]))[i]*100, DIGITS), "%"))
}
rownames(table_cat) <- levels(CAT[, VARIABLE])
table_cat <- rbind(rep("", ncol=ncol(table_cat)), table_cat)
return(table_cat)
}
table_cat <- rbind(cats(1), cats(2), cats(3))

descriptives <- rbind(table_cont, table_cat)
return(descriptives)
}
Table1(continuous, categorical)
```

It works fine. That said, for binding the categorical variables, I am doing rbind(cats(1), cats(2), cats(3)). While that is ok for this dataset, I don't want to have to keep altering that for every other dataset I use. I tried binding them in a for-loop but was unsuccessful. How does one go about binding them without repetitively specifying rbind(cats(1), cats(2), cats(3))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
table_cat <- data.frame()
# N here is the number of cat() function calls you plan on making
for(i in 1:N){
   table_cat <- rbind(table_cat,cat(i))
}
```

if you do not want that rownames issue try this:

```
table_cat <- matrix(nrow=0,ncol=ncol(cats(1)))
  for(i in 1:3){
    table_cat <- rbind(table_cat,cats(i))
  }
```

Comment: Yep that works perfectly. And I see what you did. YOu made a blank data frame. And then used rbind in a for loop. I didn't know you the data.frame() command. Thanks!

Comment: no problem. in R though, you typically want to avoid using for-loops for efficiency purposes. but I'm glad to help

Comment: Hmm just trying to understand this further. Is there a reason 11 and 21 show up as row names all of a sudden? Earlier, when I typed in Table1(continuous, categorical) that wasn't happening. Thanks for the help again but just wanted to figure this out.

Comment: you can always rename the rownames by using `rownames(Table1) <-`

Comment: Yeah I know rownames() and colnames() just didn't get why 11 and 21 appeared after using the for loop but not when I was doing rbind(cat(1), cat(2), cat(3))

Comment: i believe it is because the type of `cat()` is not a dataframe but a matrix. and with my for-loop solution I am forcing them into a dataframe structure

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: see my edited solution if you want to get rid of that rowname issue

Answer (score 0):

Unless your rows are dependent on each other, you should use functions like `apply` or `plyr`'s `ddply` to process the data without all of the for loops.

```
cont.func <- function(CONT.col, DIGITS=2){
     c(round(mean(CONT.col), DIGITS), round(sd(CONT.col), DIGITS))
}
CONT = t(apply(continuous,2,cont.func))
cat.func <- function(CAT.col,DIGITS=2){
tab = table(CAT.col)
rbind(cbind(tab, paste0(round(prop.table(tab)*100, DIGITS), "%")),"")
}
CAT = do.call("rbind",apply(categorical,2,cat.func))
rbind(CONT,c("",""),CAT)
```

Also, you can use `as.data.frame` around the `rbind` call in `cat.func` to preserve the categorical variable name when creating CAT.  This may be preferable to using blank quotes depending on your needs.

Comment: `apply` is just syntactic sugar in most cases and may or may not produce more efficient results. But I do agree that you usually want to avoid for-loops in R

Comment: True, although it's usually more consice, which makes code a lot easier to read.  If OP wanted to opt for the `plyr` library, the code could be significantly sped up with parallel processing if the data set was large.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this instead:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

better_summary = function(data){
  continuous = data %>% Filter(is.numeric, .)
  categorical = data %>% Filter(. %>% is.numeric %>% `!`, .)

  continuous_summary = 
    continuous %>%
    gather(variable, value) %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    summarize(mean = mean(value),
              sd = sd(value))

  categorical_summary = 
    categorical %>%
    gather(variable, value) %>%
    count(variable, value) %>%
    mutate(percent = n / sum(n))

  list(continuous_summary = continuous_summary,
       categorical_summary = categorical_summary)
}
```